# DynamoDB batch-write-item incorrectly encodes non-ASCII characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am using the aws CLI (aws-cli/1.12.1 Python/3.6.0 Windows/10 botocore/1.8.1) to upload some data to DynamoDB using

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://C:/users/public/data.json
```

The data.json contains German characters, such as "Ö". Here is the complete data.json

```
{
    "products": [{
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "content": {
                        "S": "Ölperlen Pfirsich"
                    },
                    "requestId": {
                        "S": "a94b879d-5bd3-4081-a672-f72d3465a4cb"
                    },
                    "userId": {
                        "S": "eu-central-1:someid"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The command succeeds; however, when the "content" attribute arrives in DynamoDb, the value looks like this:

> Ã–lperlen Pfirsich

When debugging, I can see that something goes wrong in the unpacking stage:

> 2017-11-27 08:31:17,216 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG -
>   Unpacked value of '{\n\t"products": [{\n\t\t\t"PutRequest":
>   {\n\t\t\t\t"Item": {\n\t\t\t\t\t"content": {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"S":
>   "Ã–lperlen Pfirsich"\n\t\t\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\t\t"requestId":
>   {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"S":
>   "a94b879d-5bd3-4081-a672-f72d3465a4cb"\n\t\t\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\t\t"userId":
>   {\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"S":
>   "eu-central-1:someid"\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t]\n}'
>   for parameter "request_items": OrderedDict([('requests',
>   [OrderedDict([('PutRequest', OrderedDict([('Item',
>   OrderedDict([('content', OrderedDict([('S', 'Ã–lperlen Pfirsich')])),
>   ('requestId', OrderedDict([('S',
>   'a94b879d-5bd3-4081-a672-f72d3465a4cb')])), ('userId',
>   OrderedDict([('S', 'eu-central-1:someid')]))]))]))])])])

Anyone else experienced issues writing non-ASCII characters in DynamoDb using the CLI?

Comment: Best guess, your file is not utf-8 encoded.

Comment: The file is UTF-8 encoded, but python appears to read it in using the default Windows default code page "cp1252", unless you pass a "encoding=UTF-8" argument to the file open function. I am guessing the aws cli just takes the default encoding. So I think I would either need to change the default cp in Widows (there appears to be no clear guideline how to do this) or the aws cli allows setting an "encoding" argument

Answer (score 1):

set AWS_CLI_FILE_ENCODING=UTF-8